# Disabled user by default on FOSUserbundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle and I want when each user registers to be disabled by default. The administrator will contact every user by phone and he will make user active if it's appropriate. I have read about Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Controllers but I can't figure out how to make it working. I have created RegistrationController.php in src/AppBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php with this method inside:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountStatusException;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

/**
 * Controller managing the registration
 *
 * @author Thibault Duplessis <thibault.duplessis@gmail.com>
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 */
class RegistrationController extends ContainerAware
{
    /**
     * Receive the confirmation token from user email provider, login the user
     */
    public function confirmAction($token)
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);

        if (null === $user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist', $token));
        }

        $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
        $user->setEnabled(false);
        $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());

        $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed'));
        $this->authenticateUser($user, $response);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

, but nothing works, maybe I need someone to show me the way to do it, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

For those still struggling with this question, set an observer listening the event: `fos_user.registration.initialize` like this (adapt you code path) :

```html
    app.listener.disable_registered_user:
            class: AppBundle\Observer\DisableRegisteredUserListener
            arguments:
                - "@templating"
            tags:
                # split to multiple line for readability
                # can be made into a single line like - { name: ..., event: ... , method: ... }
                -
                    name: "kernel.event_listener"
                    event: "fos_user.registration.initialize"
                    method: "disableUser"
```

Then this is the content of your event listener class :

```html
namespace AppBundle\Observer;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;

/**
 * Class DisableRegisteredUserListener
 * @package AppBundle\Observer
 */
class DisableRegisteredUserListener
{
    /**
     * @param \FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent $event
     */
    public function disableUser(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        /** @var \AppBundle\Entity\User $user */
        $user->setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just listen to the `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM` and disable the registered user again before it gets persisted to the database.

As the FOSUserBundle automatically forwards the new user to the `confirmedAction` that requires a user to be logged in, you would need to provide your own response to override this.

Your listener...

```
class DisableRegisteredUserListener
{
    /**
     * @var EngineInterface
     */
    private $templating;

    /**
     * @var EngineInterface $templating
     */
    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    /**
     * @var GetResponseUserEvent $event
     * @return null
     */
    public function disableUser(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $user->setEnabled(false);

        $response = $this->templating->renderResponse(
            'AppBundle:Registration:registration_complete.html.twig',
            array(
                'user' => $user,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Your services file (YAML)...

```
services:
    app.listener.disable_registered_user:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\DisableRegisteredUserListener
        arguments:
            - "@templating"
        tags:
            # split to multiple line for readability
            # can be made into a single line like - { name: ..., event: ... , method: ... }
            -
                name: "kernel.event_listener"
                event: "fos_user.registration.confirm"
                method: "disableUser"
```

Your `AppBundle:Registration:registration_complete.html.twig` could then be used to tell the new users that their account had been created but disabled and they would then be contacted by a member of your team to complete the process.

Comment: I don't know. Are you getting any errors? Are your logs saying anything? Have you cleared your cache? I'm going to need a little more info to give you a proper answer.